# Retrieve the file name while using file type input

Tags: java, spring, file-upload

I have a `jsp` with this code snippet in it.

```
<form name="AudioFileConversionForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" >
Choose File: <input type="file" id="audioFile" name="audioFile"><br>
<input type="submit" value="upload">
</form>
```

This is my controller in `spring`.

```
public String convertFile(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {

    String audioFile = request.getParameter("audioFile");
    System.out.println(request.getParameter("audioFile"));
    System.out.println("Audio File Conversion Successful");
}
```

I am unable to retrieve the name of the file, it shows `null`.
I know that I can retrieve the name using JQuery or javascript, but I don't want to use them both. I want to do it using pure java.
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: have you tried any of code, if yes, then let us know, whether you got the solution or not, if not then explain your requirement further.

Comment: I am trying the answers one by one. I will surely update the best suited answer from below. Thank you all for the answers.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you upload the file, `request` is instance of [`org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartHttpServletRequest.html). So you can cast it in your method `convertFile()`. See below :

```
public String convertFile(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {
    // cast request
    MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request;
    // You can get your file from request
    CommonsMultipartFile multipartFile =  null; // multipart file class depends on which class you use assuming you are using org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile

    Iterator<String> iterator = multipartRequest.getFileNames();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        String key = (String) iterator.next();
        // create multipartFile array if you upload multiple files
        multipartFile = (CommonsMultipartFile) multipartRequest.getFile(key);
    }

    // logic for conversion
}
```

> However I am unable to retrieve (receiving null value) the name of the file that I chose in the JSP page.

---> To get file name you can get it as :

```
multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();  // get filename on client's machine
multipartFile.getContentType();       // get content type, you can recognize which kind of file is, pdf or image or doc etc
multipartFile.getSize()          // get file size in bytes
```

To make file upload work, you need to make sure you are creating multipart resolver bean as below :

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">

    <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000"/>
</bean>
```

Reference : [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart)

Comment: I am accepting this answer but may I suggest you to add the code for creating an instance for `CommonsMultiPartFile`? This will help the on-goers' work easy. Or perhaps a way or a link to guide them regarding the same?

Answer (score 3):

use MultipartFile utility and try this

```
MultipartRequest multipartRequest = (MultipartRequest) request;
                Map map = multipartRequest.getFileMap();
                MultipartFile mfile = null;
                for (Iterator iter = map.values().iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
                    mfile = (MultipartFile) iter.next();
                                String fileName = mfile.getOriginalFilename()
    }
```

Or you can try apache commons file upload.

Check this link : http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html

Answer (score 2):

File name cannot be directly retrieved. You can use Apache Commons Fileupload API -

```
// Create a factory for disk-based file items
FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

// Create a new file upload handler
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

// Parse the request
List /* FileItem */ items = upload.parseRequest(request);
// Process the uploaded items
Iterator iter = items.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();

    if (item.isFormField()) {
       // Process a normal field
       String name = item.getFieldName();
       String value = item.getString();

    } else {
        // Process a file upload field 
    String fileName = item.getName();
    // DO further processing

    }
}
```

More details -

http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html

It can also be done with just Java but obviously more code will be required.

Answer (score 1):

But, first of all, you will need **Commons Fileupload API**, which will help you to use `file.getFieldName()` to display the **Form Field Name** and `file.getContentType()` to display **Type of File** and `file.getName()` to display **File Name**

```
public String convertFile(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {
  boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
    if(!isMultipart) {
            out.println("File Not Uploaded");
    }
    else{
        FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        List items = null;
        try {
            items = upload.parseRequest(request);
          } catch (FileUploadException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            FileItem file = (FileItem) items.get(0);
            out.print("Field Name :"+file.getFieldName()); // Display the field name
            out.print("Content Type :"+file.getContentType()); // Display Type of File
            out.print("File Name :"+file.getName()); // Display File Name
        } catch (Exception e) {
            out.print(e);
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: `upload.parseRequest(request)` is returning an empty list. Thus an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` on `FileItem file = (FileItem) items.get(0)`.

Comment: @Freakyuser `upload.parseRequest(request);` create array of file. If it is showing `arrayindexoutofbound` error, which means, it is getting file request.

Answer (score 0):

```
Iterator iter = items.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();

    if (item.isFormField()) {
       // Process a normal field
       String name = item.getFieldName();
       String value = item.getString();

    } else {
        // Process a file upload field 
    String fileName = item.getName();
    // DO further processing

    }
}
```