# How to send file names of Multipart file as list to front end page from controller

Tags: java, spring, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to upload files from upload button to a temp folder in server and after upload finished, i would like to see "Successful" message and uploaded filenames List.if user click on delete button from UI, I want to delete the selected file by passing filename in request.Please help me.Below is the code I have written.

```
@ResponseBody
@JsonIgnore
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadAttachment", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/html")
public List<String> uploadAttachment(final MultipartHttpServletRequest request)
{
    final List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    try
    {
        final List<MultipartFile> files = request.getFiles("files[]");
        final String orderPath = dPUploadOrderAttachmentFacade.createFolderForAttachment();
        LOG.info(orderPath);
        for (final MultipartFile file : files)
        {
            if (file.getSize() <=300000) {
            dPUploadOrderAttachmentFacade.storeTempFiles(file.getOriginalFilename(), file.getInputStream(), orderPath);
            final String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
            LOG.info(fileName);
            fileNames.add(fileName);
        }
        }
        LOG.info(fileNames);
        return fileNames;

    }
    catch (final Exception ex)
    {
        LOG.error(fileNames+"File Upload Failed due to " );
    }
    return fileNames;

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13946859/retrieve-the-file-name-while-using-file-type-input

Answer (score 0):

Add the code
request.setAttribute("filenames", fileNames);

JSP

```
 <c:forEach var = "filename" items = ${filenames}>
    ${filename}
  </c:forEach>
```

Try this